# Time Zone Problem with DST (the mysterious missing two hours)

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsdate

I have a piece of code that did work in the past (at least I think it did because otherwise the problem would have been recognized earlier). Since a few weeks, might be since DST, it began to produce incorrect results.

This snippet is supposed to generate a NSDate object referring to the first day in the given dates week at 00:00h.

```
NSCalendar *gregorianCalender = [[[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar] autorelease];
NSDate *firstDayDate;

unsigned yearAndWeek = NSTimeZoneCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit | NSWeekCalendarUnit;

// retrieve the components from the current date
NSDateComponents *compsCurrentDate = [gregorianCalender components:yearAndWeek fromDate:date];

[compsCurrentDate setWeekday:2]; // Monday
[compsCurrentDate setHour:0];
[compsCurrentDate setMinute:0];
[compsCurrentDate setSecond:0];

// make a date from the modfied components
firstDayDate = [gregorianCalender dateFromComponents:compsCurrentDate]; 

NSLog(@"MONDAY: %@", firstDayDate);
```

Today is the 24th of May so the last line should print something like

```
MONDAY: 2011-05-23 00:00:00 +0000
```

but it really prints the following

```
MONDAY: 2011-05-22 22:00:00 +0000
```

which is obviously wrong. The 22nd of May was last sunday. Now to make things weird, the result is correct again when I change the `setHour:0` to

```
[compsCurrentDate setHour:2];
```

My guess is, that there's something wrong about the timezones. But after spending half a day on the Apple documentation, google and stackoverflow I could'nt figure out what the problem is. Maybe I am using the wrong keywords or I am the only one with that problem.

Every piece of information is highly appreciated! Please let me know what you think! Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since nobody was able to answer I continued my research and discovered a simple but fatal detail in the documentation of `NSData`: the `description` method which is called when trying to print the `NSDate` as a `NSString` by default uses a "default" `NSLocale` to determine the format **and timezone**. So everything about my code was correct, the real problem I tried to fix was somewhere else and I already did this on monday .. I should RTFM more intense ;)

The following line of code prints the correct time for my timezone:

```
NSLog(@"MONDAY: %@", [firstDayDate descriptionWithLocale:[NSLocale systemLocale]]);
```

Nevertheless, during my research I discovered some interesting snippets doing basically the same thing (although the output was "wrong" as well, that's why I didn't simply replace mine). Taking all of them into consideration my attempt is working but a little bumpy. The most easy and robust I found comes from the Apple documentation itself and can also be found on various websites:

```
/* VERSION FROM APPLE DOKU */
NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

// Get the weekday component of the current date
NSDateComponents *weekdayComponents = [gregorian components:NSWeekdayCalendarUnit fromDate:date];

/*
 Create a date components to represent the number of days to subtract from the current date.
 The weekday value for Monday in the Gregorian calendar is 2, so subtract 2 from the number of days to subtract from the date in question.  (If today's Sunday, subtract 0 days.)
 */
NSDateComponents *componentsToSubtract = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[componentsToSubtract setDay: 0 - ([weekdayComponents weekday] - 2)];

NSDate *beginningOfWeek = [gregorian dateByAddingComponents:componentsToSubtract toDate:date options:0];

/*
 Optional step:
 beginningOfWeek now has the same hour, minute, and second as the original date (today).
 To normalize to midnight, extract the year, month, and day components and create a new date from those components.
 */
NSDateComponents *components =
[gregorian components:(NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit)
             fromDate: beginningOfWeek];
beginningOfWeek = [gregorian dateFromComponents:components];

NSLog(@"MONDAY: %@", [beginningOfWeek descriptionWithLocale:[NSLocale systemLocale]]);
```

Finally, to complete this: a snippet how to calculate the **last** day of the current week.

```
// reuse the "first day" to calculate the last day
NSDate *endOfLastWeek = [whateveryourobject andmethodiscalled]; 

NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

/*
 endOfLastWeek now is monday in the current week so create date components to add one week to the current date
 */
NSDateComponents *componentsToAdd = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[componentsToAdd setWeek:1];

NSDate *endOfWeek = [gregorian dateByAddingComponents:componentsToAdd toDate:endOfLastWeek options:0];

NSLog(@"SUNDAY: %@", [endOfWeek descriptionWithLocale:[NSLocale systemLocale]]);
```